# Structuring sentences without using the word "but"

Tags: sentence-patterns, syntactic-analysis

I seem to have a habit of using a lot of sentences that involve the word "but": "I haven't tried it yet, but I think it should work"; "I could easily resort to chicken, but I want to see how far I can get with alligator" etc..

It's probably deeply rooted in my style of thought, but (there I go again) I'm starting to get bored of seeing myself use this structure so often. Is there anything I can do to break free?

I know one way is to use "though" or "although", as in "Although I could easily resort to chicken, I want to see...". Anything else I could do to diversify my sentences a little?

Comment: _'There is always a "but" in this imperfect world.'_ - Anne Bronte

Comment: This question isn't better suited to writers.SE? Especially since this is about style.

Comment: Oh is it? I sort of saw the title "English Language & Usage" and figured it'd fit in here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"But" expresses ideas in opposition, not why they are in opposition, and just substituting `though`, `although`, and similar words won't change that.  Your sentence could be recast as

> Before resorting to chicken, I want to see how far I can get with alligator

(I might end up cooking the chicken) or

> Though there was chicken in the fridge, I had to try the 'gator.

(Both meats are available, and I'm ignoring the more common one.)

Comment: Awesome, that's definitely my ticket out of this but-hell. It'll take me quite a bit of practice before I can write (and think) like that, but man, will it ever be worth it. Thanks!

Comment: `but man, will it ever be worth it` Off to kind of a slow start there, aren't ya?

Comment: Yep :( The real challenge I think is in being conscious of the reason for the "but" half of the sentence. Otherwise I can't really put it in words. It'll take a while.

Comment: Just yanking your chain.  "But worth it" is such a fixed expression in English I doubt you'd really be able to recast it; you'd have to dodge it completely.

Comment: Hah, I'm sure there's nothing wrong with using it occasionally. I just don't like that it's become such a habit for me.

Comment: Hot damn, this explanation is gold to me. I have the same issue in both English and Dutch. With 2018 right around the corner, the website/blog I'm working on really needs original and well-written content to get traffic, so this really helps!

Comment: @reaper_unique -- ha, the second time in an hour I had to translate something into Dutch (_doch_ is the word you are dodging, I take it).  Just a little bit ago, I was recounting a story of maliciously frightening a Dutch woman, who shrieked "Moeder!"  These two words excepted, my Nederlandse vocabulary, consists entirely of a phrase I learned to get free beer on a trip to Amsterdam that coincided with some big soccer game, _Hup Hup Holland_.  Ping me if I can help with the English part of your blog.

Comment: Oh, will do! Pretty cool to read other people learning (a bit) of Dutch, especially because it's only spoken in like Belgium, The Netherlands and some ex-colonies of The Dutch.
To answer your remark, "doch" is a more formal way of putting it. In general people just use "maar". P.S.: just to be clear, I'm Belgian (Dutch speaking).

Comment: @reaper_unique -- then you won't be offended by the _third_ thing I had to translate, [which made the Netherlands look bad](https://wnl.tv/2017/12/27/joodse-vrouw-86-moet-belasting-betalen-tijdens-bezetting-opgebouwd-pensioen/).

Comment: @Malvolio Not at all. Why would anyone get offended by something like that?

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason for the use of "but", or "though" etc., is that the sample phrases you gave all start with a statement and are then qualified or evaluated, as if you are defending or excusing or justifying a decision. You may try phrases where you don't justify the action you are taking.

> I haven't tried it yet, but I think it should work.

compared to

> This should work. I'll try it soon.

or

> It's probably deeply rooted in my style of thought, but I'm starting to get bored of seeing myself use this structure so often.

compared to

> I'm starting to get bored of seeing myself using 'but' all the time. I wonder why I use it so much. It must be deeply rooted in my style of thought.

So, when you come across a "but" in your writing, try to put the "but" phrase at the beginning of the sentence or make it a sentence in its own right. Then analyse what you had before the "but" and see how that relates to the statement and how it can be connected.

> I want to see how far I can get with alligator. If I'm not happy with that, I can still use chicken.

No need to justify why you want to start with alligator. Be bold. You don't have to justify your decisions.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's a good way to look at it too. It's probably an effect of my over-cautious nature. Interesting how personality seeps in where you'd least expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this.

> "I could easily resort to chicken, however, I want to see how far I can get with alligator

or even

> "Easily, I could resort to chicken, although I want to see how far I can get with alligator.

This answer still seems weak to me, I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: "However" works too, however, structurally it's still more or less the same. Could it be that I'm trying to fix a non-issue or something that can't be fixed to begin with?

Comment: Okay, I seem to have misunderstood the question. I thought you were just rying to cut back on your usage of 'but'. But it seems you want to structure sentences differently. Does this sound right?

Comment: Yeah. Cutting back on "but" helps a little, but (dammit!) I'm wondering if maybe there's a completely different structure that I can "convert" my sentences to. I just worry that after a while it becomes a bit tedious reading so many sentences of the same structure. It sure does get boring writing them.

Comment: It can definitely get boring reading them, too. I think Malvolio's answer is more like what you're looking for, but I'm glad I took a shot at it.

Answer (score 1):

Use : Although, nevertheless, other than, except, excluding, save for, however...

Answer (score 1):

Would using "yet" work for you?